# How to Export table data to .csv file using codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, excel, codeigniter, export, phpexcel

I am using codeigniter, I have listed records from a table.  I want to download all the records to excel. I have used PHPExcel library but it was not supporting. Could you please help to how to achieve it?

Comment: put your code first !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using PHPExcel. Check out this link to load PHPExcel into your library file http://blog.mohamadikhwan.com/2013/01/integrating-phpexcel-into-codeigniter/

The below code is to download values in excel

```
    $this->load->library('excel');
    //Create a new Object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    // Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 



    $heading=array('Name','DOB'); //set title in excel sheet
    $rowNumberH = 1; //set in which row title is to be printed
    $colH = 'A'; //set in which column title is to be printed
    foreach($heading as $h){ 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colH.$rowNumberH,$h);
        $colH++;    
    }


    $export_excel = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY")->result_array();
    $rowCount = 2; // set the starting row from which the data should be printed
    foreach($export_excel as $excel)
    {         
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $excel['field name']); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $excel['field name']); 
        $rowCount++; 
    } 

    // Instantiate a Writer 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel5');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="part_stock."".xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
```

Comment: It's Working thank you,  I want to color the header cell($heading) with text in white and background in black

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is CSV data you don't need a library. Codeigniter supports this out of the box:

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('file');
$this->load->helper('download');
$q         =  $this->db->get($yourTableName);
$delimiter = ",";
$nuline    = "\r\n";

force_download($yourTableName.'.csv', 
               $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($q, $delimiter, $nuline));
```